# using .mjs file extension js modules

Tags: javascript, html, mime

I have a problem concerning .js and .mjs file extensions.
When I use `<script type = "module" src="test.js"></script>` as a html script import statement everything works fine.

But if I use `<script type = "module" src="test.mjs"></script>` as import statement, I get the following error message:

"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

I use a local XAMPP Apache Webserver for testing purposes. Does somebody know, how I can tell my browser that .mjs is a javascript file?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You've to configure the mime_module in httpd.conf file: `AddType application/javascript .mjs`.

Comment: Can I do it somewhere in the html as well?

Comment: No, you can't, you need to update the server configuration.

Comment: It's also possible to get the same error, if the module is not found (i.e. you've an incorrect path/filename), when the server responses with an error page (which is usually html). I'm not aware how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

If the server does not respond with the correct MIME-Type for `.mjs` or other files, you may be able to add this Type in your `.htaccess` with

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType text/javascript mjs
</IfModule>
```

That solved the problem for me.

But I also decided to use the `.js` extension again for my modules, because I think the time for `.mjs` as extension has not come yet.